# Typescript compiling and changing filenames to lowercase all the time (VS2015)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am using the latest VS2015 with the following options set in my project file for typescript:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>true</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>false</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile></TypeScriptOutFile>
    <TypeScriptOutDir></TypeScriptOutDir>
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>false</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot></TypeScriptMapRoot>
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot></TypeScriptSourceRoot>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>true</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
</PropertyGroup>
```

My problem is when it compiles a file:

```
UserService.ts it creates a userservice.js and a userservice.js.map
```

Which then contains `//# sourceMappingURL=userservice.js.map`

the userservice.js.map then has this line:

```
sources":["userservice.ts"]
```

Has anyone else seen this? I have tried recreating the files and same. This is causing me a lot of problems.

**Follow up:**

When I create a typescript file UserServicexxxx.ts everything works. When I delete all UserService files and create a UserService.ts then it goes back to doing what it did before.

I've been struggling now for 30 minutes or more trying to create UserService.ts, UserService.js and UserService.js.map  :-(

Comment: Great spot. and real pain...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue may be the cause: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2011

Have you checked that any files you reference UserService.ts from are correctly cased? If they are cased userservice.ts, it will compile to userservice.js, regardless of the actual casing of the ts file. They don't check this right now for performance reasons, but it creates odd bugs like this.

Clean your project and do a search for 'userservice.ts'. If you find one, change the case to the proper CamelCasing and recompile.

I've repro'd this issue here:

#### UserService.ts

[image: UserService.ts]

#### userService.ts

[image: userService.ts]

#### userservice.ts

[image: userservice.ts]

Check *extra* hard for any lingering links!

Comment: Chris - Thanks. I will check into this.  Been using Typescript for a long time now and have never seen this before.  Hoping this is the problem as right now every time I try to edit a file it overwrites my mixed case .js with a lowercase only.

Comment: Chris - I have done what you said. Looked everywhere for userservice.js, found one and changed it to UserService.js.  Tried everything I could. Removed everything to do with UserService.ts, js etc.  Started again and still get the same problem.  Been working on this for 90 mins now.  I wonder why others are not having similar problems.  Driving me nuts :-(

Comment: I've repro'd your issue. Check my edit. Go look EXTRA hard for any lingering links and make sure your solution is clean before you rebuild.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I wonder how many thousand man hours others will spend on this :-(   Been using typescript for a long time and never had this problem before until using it like this with VS2015.

Comment: It's a rough call. On one hand, it wasted two good hours of your time. On the other, if they made compiling take an extra 10%, you may easily spend more than that to avoid the issue. Now that you know, you can avoid it without that constant drain. Best of luck trying to reclaim those dev-hours! :)

Comment: I found even a `/// <reference path="language-service.ts" />` statement can force the compile to change the case.  Still the situation with TS 2.1

Comment: I've never looked to see if there's any issue filed on this topic. I'd imagine when there are conflicts or case-mismatches, they could issue a warning. I'd encourage you to create an issue on their GitHub if you have a recent repro.